# Other checkboxes in different rows are checked when a checkbox is checked

Tags: wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have a grid and each row (300 of them) consists of "string | string | int | string | check." If for example I click on the checkbox in row 7, nothing out of the ordinary happens. But if I click another checkbox on another row, I may get 10 other rows with their checkboxes checked, but these other checkboxes arent executing the code associated with them.

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Add">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                           
                        <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because row visuals are reused. You could set `<DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="False"...` but that will have a huge performance impact if there are many rows. A better solution is to use a ViewModel to store the check state. Then bind the value to the ViewModel `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyBoolProperty}"...`

In your ViewModel you can call your method when the property changes.

```
public class MyItem
{
    //.... other class info
    //TODO: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

    private bool _MyBoolProperty = false;
    public bool MyBoolProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyBoolProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _MyBoolProperty = value;
            MyBoolPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void MyBoolPropertyChanged()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```